# KDE Rounded borders when maximized

Tags: kde, window-decoration

In KDE (4.9 or Project Neon), how do I keep rounded borders for even maximized windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type *window* into the **K**ickoff menu, go to
**Window Behavior** → **Moving** and enable **Display borders on maximized windows**.

This setting can be quite annoying, though, if you're used to closing windows by clicking carelessly in the top right corner...

Comment: Where is 'KDE Control Module'?

Comment: Aha! Got it! Thanks! I was searching in Window Appearance ...

Comment: Well, I've positioned my main panel to the top, so I'm not used to clicking the top-right corner to close windows :)

Comment: Please read Liso's answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Display borders on maximized windows** *is removed* from kde 4.11. See -> https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=299245 or http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-kde/2013-08/msg00002.html

(I am trying not to make statements based on my opinion about this ... "solution" :P )

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You are right. :) I added essential part. (I have not enough reputation points (50) to add comment to Oleh's answer, where it could be more useful :/)